# Distinct values in an excel data source

Tags: c#, excel

I have a source excel file where my "key" is held in column B. I want to add rows that contain different distinct key values to different tables in a database, using a list of datatables to allow for the number of distinct keys to be variable.

Is it better practise to select the distinct records straight from the sheet itself, or to pull the entire sheet into a "master" datatable and query the datatable for my separate values?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you first use distinct and then filter records, it will improve speed and performance.

Comment: So the former? (`select distinct key from excel`)

Comment: Yes, you just need to specify proper optimized query/code otherwise it might affect your performance.